# Why these icons don't combine while my taskbar buttons group policy is "always combine"?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

my system is Win7 Ultimate 32bit, and my taskbar buttons group poliy is "Always combine, hide laybels".

There is one program that have some shortcuts, when I open that program by clicking different shortcuts, I found that the icons didn't combine as the policy says.

All these shortcuts are targeted to the same position.
Can anyone tell me why this happen and how to combine all these icons?
Thanks

PS:The system says that I am a new user and have no right to post images....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications do have some control over their taskbar appearance but the shortcut used to start them also matters. If one shortcut specifies a [App Model Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a different shortcut does not (One you created perhaps?) then Windows might decide that these are two different apps (Or the same app with separate "modes")

If the application does not call [SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then the auto generated Id might also not match if you run 32 and 64 bit versions of the same app...